# How to test that an element doesn't exist with RSpec?

Tags: rspec, capybara

How can I test that an element doesn't exist?
I tried the following but get the error `textarea#Question1Text does not exist` instead of a passing tests.

```
it "should not have question 1" do
  find('textarea#Question1Text').should_not be
end

it { should_not find('textarea#Question1Text') }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use one of the capybara matchers (specifically `have_css`) to test if an element exists or not.

```
it 'should not have question1' do
  page.should_not have_css('textarea#Question1Text')
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue with the ways suggested to do this is that they will have race conditions if, for example, after clicking a button it hides a field. In this case it will grab the page after the button has been clicked but before the javascript has had a chance to find it, so your test may fail. It tends to be intermittent and will primarily happen with fast headless browsers like phantomjs.

Instead I suggest you use something like:

```
expect(page).to have_selector("#id_of_element")
```

This will wait until the condition is true, but will still timeout quickly if it fails.

Answer (score 1):

easy peasy

```
expect{page.find_by_id("update-#{term1.id}").should}.not_to raise_error
expect{page.find_by_id("update-#{term4.id}")}.to  raise_error
```

if you don't have unique Ids then Css as spullen suggest will work